# Get image width and height synchronously in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I don't know how to get image width and height synchronously. Please correct the below code.

I have tried many ways to get image width and height in direct way.

```
getImageSize(url){
      var img = new Image()
      img.src = url
      img.onload = function(){
        return [img.width, img.height]
      }
    } 
    getImageUrl(obj){
      let vm = this
      let reader = new FileReader()
      reader.readAsDataURL(obj)
      reader.onload =  function() {
        return reader.result
      }

    }
    async getImageSize(imgObj){
      let base64URI = await this.getImageUrl(imgObj)
      let size = await this.getImageSize(base64URI)
      return size
    }

   beforeuploadImage(event){
      let imgsize = this.getImageSize(imgObj)
      imgsize  = imgsize.split(",")
      console.log(imgsize[0], imgsize[1])
   }
```

I need to get image width and height in `beforeuploadImage` method directly

Comment: you can't - because "reading the image" is an asynchronous operation

Comment: note, you can't await `this.getImageUrl` or `this.getImageSize` because neither of those functions return a Promise (they both `return undefined` as those functions have no return statement in them)

Comment: @JoshiPattabhi Please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise for usage of promise.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/mRaSeGDE looks synchronous, but it isn't - but at least the code will work like you expect

Comment: `getImageUrl(obj) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload =  function() {
            var img = new Image()
            img.src = reader.result
            img.onload = function(){
                resolve(JSON.stringify({'width': img.width, 'height': img.height}))
            };
            img.onerror = reject;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(obj)
        reader.onerror = reject
      })
    }`
I have reduced code, How do I get value without async function